# drag an object within a defined area only

Tags: objective-c

I have an object I want the user to be able to drag along a defined area across the screen, not just anywhere on the screen. I want it to move across the screen (x axis) at a specific height on the screen (y axis), therefor, the user can move the object anywhere along the x axis while maintaining a set position on the y axis.

If my co-ordinates are right...

I want the object to start at 500x, 580y and then the user can drag object along x axis anywhere between say 20x to 990x while maintaining the objects position on the y axis of 580.

Here is what I have so far....the commented out parts // are the parts I'm trying but don't work....

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
//CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:touch.view]; 
//CGPoint yLocation=CGPointMake(object.center.x,location.y) object.center=yLocation;

    if([touch view] ==myimage)
{
    myimage.center = touchLocation;
}
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
//new Draggable('myimage',
              //{snap: function(y)
                 // {return[ (y<1024)?(y>0?y:0):1024];
                  //}
              //}
 //CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:touch.view]; 
// CGPoint yLocation=CGPointMake(object.center.x,location.y) object.center=yLocation;

    if([touch view] ==myimage)

    if([touch tapCount] ==2)
    {
        myimage.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (3.141592654); //M_PI*1.00

    }

 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting your images center point to the location of the touch. This will move the image to wherever your touch is. To control one axis at a time you just need to break down the touch location to the X and Y axis and only update the X or Y coordinate of the image you are moving. Meanwhile each update would just always use a static coordinate that you want to remain the same. This should give you the results you are looking for. I'm pretty sure the rest of your code for dragging is not needed.

Example:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
myImage.center = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, 580);
//Here we just use the X coordinate of the touch
//We make a new point location and use 580 always since we never
//want the Y axis to move. This should give you an image that moves
//left or right as you move your finger but never up and down.
```